# How to prove unicity in a disjunction of $n$ propositions

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Let's suppose I have the propositions $\varphi_1, \varphi_2,...,\varphi_n$ and I want to prove that there happens exactly one of them. How do you do it? To do it the hard way I guess we first need to prove that at least one of them is true. Then there's the options of taking every pair $\varphi_i, \varphi_j$ to be true and then derive a contradiction, but this is a tedious task when $n$ is too long.

**Edit:** the clearest example that comes to mind is to prove a transitive relation on a set $A$ to be a strict linear ordering. This means I need to show trichotomy in the relation, meaning for all $x,y\in A$ there's only one possibility: $xRy, yRx,$ or $x=y$. How do you usually prove this to begin with?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think that would only prove that at least one of the three options holds: $xRy,yRx$, or $x=y$. How do you assure that exactly one of them holds?

Comment: It seems to me that you want to prove that the following statement holds$$ \bigwedge_{i}^{n} (\varphi_i \rightarrow \bigwedge_{j}^{n-\{i\}} \neg \varphi_j)$$
I confess I am not sure if there would be a better way then proving this (in the laborious) direct way though (assuming $\varphi_i$ to hold and deriving the consequent, for every $i$).